# Kendo want to add specific label for each graph point

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo charts and want to add a specific label to each point on the graph, not related to the data value of that point, but rather a symbol relating to a qualitative property of that point.

In this code, I am able to customize the label on a per-series basis, where the default is an up-arrow, India is a *, and Russian Federation is a space. But it doesn't let me vary the label on a per-point basis within each series. Any way to do that? Any way to have an array of label values for each series, or something like that?

Thanks!

--Bruce

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/column">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart" style="background: center no-repeat url('../content/shared/styles/world-map.png');"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "top"
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column",
                    labels: {template: "↑",
                             visible: true, color: 'red',
                                   position: "outsideEnd"}
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "India",
                    data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855],
                    labels: {template: "*"}
                }, {
                    name: "Russian Federation",
                    data: [4.743, 7.295, 7.175, 6.376, 8.153, 8.535, 5.247, -7.832, 4.3, 4.3],
                    labels: {template: " "}
                }, {
                    name: "Germany",
                    data: [0.010, -0.375, 1.161, 0.684, 3.7, 3.269, 1.083, -5.127, 3.690, 2.995]
                },{
                    name: "World",
                    data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727]
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0}%"
                    },
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    axisCrossingValue: 0
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011],
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    labels: {
                        padding: {top: 135}
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}%",
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should be the rule to determine the label for each point? The point's index determines its label or something else?

Comment: I have a formula that will be generating a different value for each data point, based on how that data point has changed over time, and/or how many original data items went into computing that data point. For example, if all the data points are the average of numbers in a survey, I'll want the label to reflect whether or not there were at least 5 survey responses used in computing the average. Bottom line, let's assume that I'll generate an array of labels, similar to the array of series data values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used your code to build a solution. You might not use it exactly as it is but you'll get the general idea. See [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tWNBLek5yoZK8eth8ZcL?p=preview).

Basically what I did was the following:

1) Convert the series' items into objects with two fields, one is the actual data and the other is the label identifier.

```
data: [{value: 1, label: 0}, {value: 2, label: 1}, {value: 3, label: 2}],
```

2) Make a function that converts the template object (e) to the right label string.

```
let labels = {
    "India": ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
    "Russian Federation": [2, 4, 6]
};

let getLabel = function(e) {
    return labels[e.series.name][e.dataItem.label];
};
```

3) Place the function in the template field of the series.

```
seriesDefaults: {
    labels: {
        template: getLabel
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shai this looks like just what I wanted. Question: How does Kendo know to pull out the values to graph from the "value" key in the array element object instead of using the array element directly as the value?

Comment: It's the default for the `series.field` setting. You can read about it [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.field).

Comment: Notice I changed the `template` setting to be under `seariesDefaults`. This will make it easier since you only need to write it once for all series.

Comment: If it solves your problem, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Fantastic, accepted. I ended up having to change the GetLabel function to get the data somewhere else, to fit our existing data model, but the overall approach worked perfectly.

Comment: One follow-on issue that we are fighting with (I'm not asking it as a separate question until we work at it some more) is that we need to transmit the Kendo chart spec as JSON, which fails on the function name as a value. Using functions in Kendo specs like this is amazingly flexible, but it looks like it's hard to make it play well with other components in a big system.
Anyway, thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **[visual property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.labels.visual)** of the labels to set the text based on value:

```
seriesDefaults: {
    type: "column",
    labels: {
             visible: true, color: 'red',
             position: "outsideEnd",
             visual: function(e) {
                var center = e.rect.center();
                var val = parseFloat(e.text);
                var text = "↑";
                if (val > 4) text = "*";
                if (val > 7) text = " ";
                return new kendo.drawing.Text(text, [center.x, e.rect.origin.y], {
                    fill: {
                      color: "red"
                    }
                });
                }

            }
},
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uGugI)**

Comment: Thanks @ezanker I had thought of something like this but it means that the label is a function only of the value and not of the category and series dimensions. In many cases what you wrote would be perfect but in my case I may need different labels for the same data values at different graph coordinates. Thanks!